# Deleting data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-delete

```
create table Person(
    SSN INT,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    primary key(SSN)
);
create table Company(
CompanyID INT,
Name VARCHAR(20)
primary key(SSN)

create table Car(
    PlateNr INT,
    Model VARCHAR(20),
    primary key(PlateNr)
);

create table CarOwner(
    SSN INT,
    PlateNr INT,
    primary key(SSN, PlateNR)
    foreign key(SSN) references Person (SSN),
    foreign key(PlateNr) references Car (PlateNr)
);

create table CompanyWorker(
    SSN INT,
    CompanyID INT
    primary key(SSN, CompanyID),
    foreign key(SSN) references Person (SSN),
    foreign key(CompanyID) references Company (CompanyID)
);

Insert into Person(SSN, Name) VALUES ('123456789','Max');
Insert into Person(SSN, Name) VALUES ('123456787','John');
Insert into Person(SSN, Name) VALUES ('123456788','Tom');

insert into Company(CompanyID, Name) VALUES('1','IKEA');
insert into Company(CompanyID, Name) VALUES('2','Starbucks');

Insert into Car(PlateNr, Model) VALUES ('123ABC','Volvo');
Insert into Car(PlateNr, Model) VALUES ('321CBA','Toyota');
Insert into Car(PlateNr, Model) VALUES ('333AAA','Honda');

Insert into CarOwner(SSN, PlateNr) VALUES ('123456789','123ABC');
Insert into CarOwner(SSN, PlateNr) VALUES ('123456787','333AAA');
Insert into CarOwner(SSN, PlateNr) VALUES ('123456788','321CBA');

insert into CompanyWorker(SSN, CompanyID) VALUES('123456789','1');
insert into CompanyWorker(SSN, CompanyID) VALUES('123456787','1');
```

This is my tables and insert into those tables and the problem I'm having is deleting a person. I want to be able to delete a person from the "Person" table, example

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE SSN = '123456789';
```

But the problem is that I have to delete the person from all the other tables that said person have a relation with. Person have relations with CarOwner and CompanyWorker. Sure, I could simply execute 3 seperate delete-statements at once:

```
DELETE FROM Person WHERE SSN = '123456789';
DELETE FROM CarOwner WHERE SSN = '123456789';
DELETE FROM CompanyWorker WHERE SSN = '123456789';
```

But then if this SSN doesn't exist in CompanyWorker I will run into problems since it's trying to delete something that doesnt exist there. So I need to somehow be able to check if it exists first before deleting somehow, this is my problem.

Comment: "But then if this SSN doesn't exist in CompanyWorker I will run into problems since it's trying to delete something that doesnt exist there. So I need to somehow be able to check if it exists first before deleting somehow, this is my problem.", no it won't, it just won't delete anything. If the SSN doesn't exist, there won't be an error, it simply won't delete anything. Having 3 delete statements is fine.

Comment: No problem of having 3 delete statements, it won't crash because your SSN doens't exist, it'll just delete no rows. You can add DELETE CASCADE clause on your Foreign key so when your delete a PERSON it'll delete all the rows associated to in the other tables.

Comment: Look up referential integrity and cascading delete - should give you what you need.

Comment: If you want to make sure to delete maximum rows from each table in any case (to prevent mistakenly wrong parameters) you could add `DELETE FROM ..... LIMIT 1`

Comment: You are right. It worked when I changed the order I was deleting. If I had DELETE FROM Person first I complain about foreign keys from the other relations. But if I put DELETE FROM CarOwner and DELETE FROM CompanyWorker first it worked just fine. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you use MSSQL as database engine, you can ALTER TABLE to add a FOREIGN CONSTRAINT with ON DELETE CASCADE

```
ALTER TABLE CarOwner
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CarOwner_SSN 
        FOREIGN KEY (SSN) 
        REFERENCES Person (SSN) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
```